# Multiple cors sites on Traefik

Tags: docker-compose, cors, traefik

I'm using Traefik on my Ubuntu server. Cors works fine for one website but when I try to use it for two they seem to conflict. What is the correct syntax?

This is what I have in my docker-compose file:

Service 1:

```
  - "traefik.http.routers.service-one.middlewares=cors"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors.headers.accesscontrolallowmethods=GET,OPTIONS,PUT"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors.headers.accesscontrolalloworiginlist=https://site1.com,https://site2.com,https://site2.com"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors.headers.accesscontrolmaxage=100"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors.headers.addvaryheader=true"
```

Service 2:

```
  - "traefik.http.routers.service-two.middlewares=cors"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors.headers.accesscontrolallowmethods=GET,OPTIONS,PUT"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors.headers.accesscontrolalloworiginlist=https://site1.com,https://site2.com,https://site2.com"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors.headers.accesscontrolmaxage=100"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors.headers.addvaryheader=true"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same CORS middleware, lets separate them in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
services:
  service1:
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.service-one.middlewares=cors-service1"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-service1.headers.accesscontrolallowmethods=GET,OPTIONS,PUT"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-service1.headers.accesscontrolalloworiginlist=https://site1.com,https://site2.com"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-service1.headers.accesscontrolmaxage=100"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-service1.headers.addvaryheader=true"

  service2:
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.service-two.middlewares=cors-service2"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-service2.headers.accesscontrolallowmethods=GET,OPTIONS,PUT"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-service2.headers.accesscontrolalloworiginlist=https://site1.com,https://site2.com"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-service2.headers.accesscontrolmaxage=100"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors-service2.headers.addvaryheader=true"
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! I was under the wrong impression that I have to explicitly reference a middleware called cors.

Comment: You welcome :))